# expand y-axis palantir foundry workshop chart to see all the name

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-workshop

as stated, how can I expand y-axis chart in Palantir foundry workshop to see all the name? I couldnt find a way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

In the plot layer config panel you could set the X-axis Property limit to a very high number (e.g. 5,000). This section of the config will be called the X-axis Property regardless of the chart's orientation. However, this won't get you "all" of the results if you have a large number of results, but it will display quite a few.

[screenshot showing how to change the limit property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jk8V0.jpg)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: So, basically, there is nothing we can do to display the full names in Y-axis since the adjustment is done internally, right? For instance, if we got a large numbers of results, we need to delimit them to a certain number so the data can be displayed properly.

Comment: I think I may have misinterpreted your question. I thought you were primarily asking about seeing more items on the y-axis but it sounds like you're actually seeking to display the full names of the items on the y-axis. Is that right? I don't think Workshop gives you that level of customization. One option that might be to create a [Vega Plot](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/quiver/cards-vega-plot/) in Quiver and [embed that chart in Workshop](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/quiver/dashboards-workshop/).